# How to align stacked Font-Awesome icons correctly

Tags: html, css, font-awesome

I have been at this for way too long and have yet to figure out how to stack four font-awesome icons on top of each other. I've gotten to three but I am wanting my icons to look like this [image: four stacked icons] (sorry for crummy image)

Here's the HTML for my three stacked.

```
<span class="fa-stack fa-4x">
<i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x icon-background4"></i>
<i class="fa fa-circle-thin fa-stack-2x icon-background6"></i>
<i class="fa fa-cutlery fa-inverse fa-stack-1x"></i>
</span>
```

The CSS

```
.icon-stack-1x {
  line-height: inherit;
}
.icon-stack-2x {
  font-size: 1.5em;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

set `display:flex` on `.fa-cutlery` and `.fa-inverse` to `.fa-circle-thin`

and `background-color` to `span`

```css
body {
  background: red
}
span {
  background: black;
  border-radius: 100%
}
.fa-cutlery {
  display: flex
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<span class="fa-stack fa-4x">
  <i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x"></i>
  <i class="fa fa-circle-thin fa-stack-2x fa-inverse"></i>
  <i class="fa fa-cutlery fa-inverse fa-stack-1x"></i>
</span>
```

Comment: Oh awesome. I do want to clarify as I'm trying this out. When you say put flex on .fa-inverse to .fa-circle-thin that means what exactly? Just want to clarify.

Comment: I said: set `display:flex`(property) on `.fa-cutlery` **and**  (add/set class) `.fa-inverse` (to the icon which has class) `.fa-circle-thin`